# calculating the mean speed by the hour in R

Tags: r

I have a large Data set of cars speeds measured in  a high way for one year.

the file have the following columns:

```
1.TimeStamp- 31/12/13 23:48:51
2.Speed- 97.6
```

I want to calculate the mean speed in each hour of the day, like that:

```
*23:00-00:00- 110.8
*00:00-01:00- 96.17
```

how can I do that in R?
in R I have the folowing columns:

```
 $ TimeStamp        : POSIXct, format: "2012-12-31 23:48:41
 $ Speed            : num  97.2 
 $ Date             : Date, format: "2012-12-31" 
 $ Time             :Class 'times'  atomic [1:100000] 0.992 0.992 0.992 0.992 0.993 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "format")= chr "h:m:s"
```

I ran dput(test2[1:3,])

```
> dput(test2[1:3,])
structure(list(RoadId = c(12L, 12L, 12L), UnitId = c(283398L, 
283398L, 283398L), TimeStamp = structure(c(1356990521, 1356990531, 
1356990541), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), Speed = c(97.2, 
97.2, 97.2), VehicleType = c(214L, 214L, 214L)), .Names = c("RoadId", 
"UnitId", "TimeStamp", "Speed", "VehicleType"), row.names = c(NA, 
3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: please post the result of `dput(df[1:3,])` where `df` is name of your dataframe.

Comment: @ujjwal Why are you attempting to undo typos that I've corrected?

Comment: @eliranazulay That wasn't to you it was to the user attempting to edit your question, picked it up form the review queue.

Comment: I ran the command @ujjwal asked me "dput(df[1:3,])" on my dataframe, and pasted the result in the comment

Comment: Putting it in a comment is not good practice as it's difficult to format code so it is usable in a comment, you should update your question instead.

Comment: @Lankymart sorry for that, didn't realise. Go ahead

Comment: @ujjwal It's not up to me now depends on the review gods on whether it gets approved. I'll roll it back if it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this helps

```
res <- do.call(`data.frame`, aggregate(Speed~
                 cbind(Hour=format(TimeStamp,'%H')), test2, mean))
res$Hour
#Hour 
# 16 
#Levels: 16


res$Hour <- as.numeric(as.character(res$Hour))
with(res, plot(Hour, Speed))
```

Comment: how I can I plot the reasults I got?

Comment: your first comment worked, I want to plot the reasult in a graph

Comment: @eliranazulay Have you tried `with(res, plot(Hour, Speed))`

Comment: when I run the first line I get an ERROR:
res <- do.call(test2, aggregate(Speed~cbind(Hour=format(TimeStamp,'%H')), test2, mean))

Error in do.call(test2, aggregate(Speed ~ cbind(Hour = format(TimeStamp,  : 
  'what' must be a character string or a function

Comment: @eliranazulay  You said earlier, that the first comment worked.

Comment: yes it did, now I just want to plot the reasults in a graph X=hour Y=speed

Comment: @eliranazulay  Then what is the `Error` if it worked?  here the `res$Hour` is a `factor` column.  I converted to `numeric` in the 2nd line as `as.numeric(as.character(`.  I am able to plot (3rd line) the result with the data you provided.

Comment: @eliranazulay  As I don't have the full `hour`, here is an example that replicates `set.seed(24);res1 <- data.frame(Hour=1:16, Speed=rnorm(16,90)); with(res1, plot(Hour, Speed, type='l'))`

Comment: I used your first comment: `aggregate(Speed~cbind(Hour=format(TimeStamp,'%H')), test2, mean)`
it worked great, now I want to plot the data I got, I tried saving the reasult into 'res' like that: `aggregate(Speed~cbind(Hour=format(TimeStamp,'%H')), test2, mean)->res`.
 but when I type res$Hour I get NULL, res$Speed gives me the correct speeds

Comment: @eliranazulay That is why I updated the post with `res <- do.call(data.frame, aggregate(Speed~
                 cbind(Hour=format(TimeStamp,'%H')), test2, mean)); res$Hour#Hour 
  16`

Comment: Ok but when I type: `res <- do.call(data.frame, aggregate(Speed~ cbind(Hour=format(TimeStamp,'%H')), test2, mean))` I get an Error:

Comment: @eliranazulay  I am using `R 3.1.2` on linux

Comment: @eliranazulay  If it doesn't work, you can do `res1 <- data.frame(Hour=res[[1]],Speed=res$Speed)` from the `res` you created from first comment

Comment: Worked great thnk you!

Comment: @eliranazulay  Glad to know that it worked.  But, still I wonder, how you got that error...

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `cut` to extract the hours from the `TimeStamp` column.

```
test2$hour <- cut(test2$TimeStamp, breaks="hour")
aggregate(test2$Speed,by=list(test2$hour),FUN=mean)
#              Group.1    x
#1 2013-01-01 03:00:00 97.2
```

Comment: It also works but it gives the mean by hour and by date, I need the mean only by the hour